# Symfony $request->getContent() in bad format?

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, http, request

i send a request to my symfony backand via

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/example/example",
    method: "POST",
    data: { test: "hallo", test2 : "hallo2" },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
    ...
```

but my i become in controller when i use $request->getContent() the following output:

```
test=hallo&test2=hallo
```

but i need the json formatted content, how i can get this from the request? Like so:

```
[
    {"test" : "hallo"},
    {"test2" : "hallo2"}
]
```

Comment: The output suggests that you never sent json to begin with, so the mistake is in the client not the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending JSON data to your backend, you can use `JSON.strinify` to do this.

```
var data = [
    {"test" : "hallo"},
    {"test2" : "hallo2"}
];
jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
    url: "/example/example",
    method: "POST",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
    ...
```